# Passing in a list through AJAX in Django

Tags: django, ajax, django-views

On the backend, I have a request that needs to get updated when ajax is called.

```
options = request.GET.getlist('Options')
```

By, default it is an empty list [], but when I send data through ajax it is returning a stringed array within an array.

```
data: {'Options':JSON.serialize(["Fruit"])}
```

On the backend, it returns --> **[ ' [ "Fruit" ] ' ]**

If, I pass in a string, like 'Fruit'

```
data: {'Options': "Fruit")}
```

then I get my expected result on the backend --> **[ 'Fruit' ]**

This is okay, but not for multiple values, how can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You deserialize it to a Python list with:

```
from json import loads as jloads

options = jloads(request.GET['Options'])
```

or if we do not for sure if the item is passed, we can for example work with a default:

```
from json import loads as jloads

options = jloads(request.GET.get('Options', 'null'))
```